# $\mu^*$-measurable and countability

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Given $X$ an uncountable set and define $\mu^*$: ${\cal P}(X) \to [0, \infty]$ by $\mu^*(E)= 0$ when $E$ is countable and $\mu^*(E) = 1$  when $E$ is uncountable.

Prove that $\forall A \subseteq X$, $A$ is $\mu^*$-measurable $\iff $ $A$ is countable or $A^c$ is countable.

I finished most of the proof but I got stuck when I assmue that $E$ is uncountable, and suppose that $A$ is $\mu^*$-measurable, that is $\mu^*(E) = \mu^*(E \cap A) + \mu^*(E \cap A^c)$, that is, either $E \cap A$ is countable or $E \cap A^c$ is countable. But how to arrive the conclusion that either $A$ is countable or $A^c$ is countable? I tried to assume both $A$ and $A^c$ are uncountable for contradiction but I failed. Hope to get some help here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that $A$ is measurable iff for all sets $E$ we have $\mu^*(E) = \mu^*(E \cap A) + \mu^*(E \cap A^c)$.  So to prove that $A$ is not measurable, we just have to come up with one particular set $E$ for which this equation fails.

Try $E=X$.